# Roundcube imap domain

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot, roundcube

I have configuration Postfix+dovecot+roundcube. I have installed certificate SSL on domain `main.example.com` so when I have added below imap configuration test is OK and roundcube works.

[image]

When I write username and password I can login but I don't know why I don't have to write full username with domain?

Second of my problem is after login I see user in domain mail.example.com but I want to domain example.com.
When I add parameter `$config['username_domain'] ='example.com';` in `config.inc.php`, then I am not able to log to roundcube.

Answer (score 0):

the need for domain part is handled by dovecot. default dovecot configuration should work for local users without domain.

mail.example.com appears to be your system name. if you want your roundcube to show example.com you need to change your realm to example.com.
try setting auth_default_realm  in dovecot config to 'example.com' and then try logging in with 'user@example.com'

it might work, or you might need to change something else too...
either way, make backups before making changes

Comment: I found solution of my issue. I have changed parameter in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf to `auth_username_format = %{if;%d;eq;example.com;%Ln}` and now have to write user@example.com to login.